# Headings don't collapse in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, styles

I am using Office 365. I have styled a document with body text, Heading One, Heading Two etc.

I want to be able just to see the Heading Ones. I click right click the Heading One and then Expand/Collapse and then collapse all headings.

I should just be able to see the Headings 1s. However, nothing happens. I see all the formatting.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The subsequent headings - Heading 2, Heading 3 - do collapse, but the body text remains. I want to see only the Heading 1s. I don't know how to do this.

Comment: Add to your question: Put your comment in the question.  A good screenshot might improve your question.

Comment: Did you mean heading 1 still displays the body content after it is collapsed?Can Heading 2 and Heading 3 collapse properly?In addition, if you want to collapse all headings in word and only show the contents of Heading1, this is not feasible